# Symfony Login Form TODO: provide a valid redirect inside C:\xampp\htdocs\LicentaTenis\src\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator.php

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am new to symfony and this is my first project and I'm trying to create a login form. I created it using make:auth, but when I try to login I get this error:
[image: provide a valid redirect inside error]

I replaced

```
throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
```

with

```
return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('home'));
```

but it shows me the same error.

This is my home route:

```
/**
* @Route("/", name="home")
* @Method({"GET"})
*/
public function index(){
    return $this->render('tenis/index.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: I had the same error, what did you do to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

For the first solution, you can just make a null return in the **onAuthenticationSuccess(...)** function *(line 99 of your AppCustomAthenticator.php)* if you don't have any particular processing to do when the User has connected with success and add the redirection route directly in the **./config/packages/security.yaml** file like this.

```
security:
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g.switch_user) #
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email

encoders:
    # use your user class name here
    App\Entity\User:
        # Use native password encoder
        # This value auto-selects the best possible hashing algorithm
        # (i.e. Sodium when available).
        algorithm: auto

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        form_login:
            login_path: app_login
            check_path: app_login
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager # It's optional
            default_target_path: home # add here your redirect path
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        guard:                                        # you need to check this file and 
            authenticators:                           # make sure that all your configurations 
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator # are right
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_login
```

Or you can comment out the line 99 of your AppCustomAthenticator.php (in the onAuthenticationSuccess(...) function)

```
  throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
```

and change it to.

```
return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('home'));
```

You can change the value of 'home' by the name of your redirect symfony route.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save the change. If it does not work, try to clear the cache:

`bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: I use PhpStorm and it saves all the changes automatically. I also cleared the cache using bin/console cache:clear, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did it still show the exception `throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__); ` with the line 100 ? No make sense

Answer (score 0):

In your SecurityAuthenticator file, find the function SecurityAuthenticator  and uncomment this line:
return new RedirectResponse ($ this-> urlGenerator-> generate ('home'));
to put your redirection